# Unable to connect to PostgreSQL database from LoadRunner script

Tags: database, postgresql, load-testing, loadrunner

I am trying to connect to PostgreSQL database from LR script, but unable to do so.

Please find below the steps performed:-

1. Downloaded & installed 32 bit  PostgreSQL Unicode ODBC driver in a 64 bit Windows machine.
2. Created a System DSN with name ( PostgreSQL32W).
3. Tested the connection, all good.
4. From the LR script, made use of   lr_db_connect function:-

   ```
   lr_db_connect("StepName=PostgreSQL32W",
    "ConnectionName=PostgreSQL32W",
    "ConnectionString=Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode};Server=X.Y.Z.W;Database=***;Trusted_Connection=False;User=****;Password=****",
    "ConnectionType=ODBC",
    LAST);
   ```

After executing the block of code, i am getting the below error:-

Action.c(81): DB Connection failed {"ERROR [08001] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Sohit Kanwar""}

The issue is, no where i am using "Sohit Kanwar", as the username. This is the my logged in windows username & not the username i have used in LR connection string.

Any help in this regards will be useful.

Thank you.

Comment: Step 1: Can you connect with this driver outside of LoadRunner

Comment: Hi James, i did narrow down the problem. I have setup a local postgreSQL DB in my local & changed my connection string to point to 127.0.0.1 (localhost), It is able to connect.

The database server, i am trying to connect is remote. But i am able to ping from command prompt i.e. able to connect to remote database server outside LR script.

Now the problem is, only from LoadRunner i am not able to connect & gets this error.

Comment: Did you hand code the connection string or record an ODBC client, such as MSQuery included in excel?

Comment: Yes, i have hardcoded the database server IP. In the above snapshot of Load Runner script,  "Server=X.Y.Z.W" points to a static IP address. 

From my local machine (where VuGen is setup), i am able to ping to that static IP address. However, from Load Runner script execution, I get the error message "Action.c(81): DB Connection failed {"ERROR [08001] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "Sohit Kanwar""}"

My confusion is, from where my windows login username is used to authenticate. Because i have not mentioned this username anywhere in my Load Runner scipt.

Comment: Record a client which is working, rather than hand code the connection.  You may find a difference in the connection string and the queries